# How to find out which resources are not used in an android app

Tags: android, resources

I would like to know if there is the way to find out which resources (layouts, strings, colors etc. from ***res-folder***) are not used in my android project.

What I mean, in my app I have some old strings, which won't be used anymore and I would like to remove them from the string.xml

Thank you in advance.

**Ps.**
I'm using Eclipse for developing

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A swift google search brought up this project: http://code.google.com/p/android-unused-resources/

After running the jar, all the unused resources of your project are being displayed.

To run the jar just call `java -jar AndroidUnusedResources.jar`.

Comment: @keyboardsurfer  but how to use the jar. please share the code. thanks :)

Comment: I've updated my answer. Also It's described on the project's website at the time I'm writing this.